# Обособленное обстоятельство

Tags: пунктуация, обстоятельство

Я недавно в справочнике Розенталя наткнулась на одно предложение с обособленным обстоятельством.

"Я, тоже с узлом на спине, семенил за нею."
Семенить - идти маленькими шагами.
Раз это обстоятельство, то вопрос задается от "сменил". Сменил как? тоже с узлом на спине. Как-то не очень смотрится. Может, все дело в слове " тоже"?
Я, с рюкзачком за спиной, шла домой. Я какая? с рюкзачком. (Розенталь про обособленное определение: "Бабы, с длинными граблями в руках, бредут в поле." Намеренный отрыв.)

Я, с топором в руках, рубил дерево. Здесь тоже обстоятельство? Рубил как? с топором в руках. Или я какой? с топором в руках?

Егорка, с топором за поясом, в тулупе и шапке, возвращался из леса. Здесь-то это явно обособленное определение. Егорка какой? с ... и шапке.

Помогите разобраться, а то я уже запуталась!

Answer (score 1):

**Розенталь**

http://modernlib.net/books/rozental_ditmar_elyashevich/spravochnik_po_russkomu_yaziku_punktuaciya/read/

§ 20. Обособленные обстоятельства

***Я, тоже с узлом на спине, семенил за нею.***

Я думаю, что это **обособленное несогласованное определение**, а не обстоятельство. Сравнить: Бабы, с длинными граблями в руках, бредут в поле (обособленное несогласованное определение).

Наречие ТОЖЕ входит в определительный оборот: кто-то  тоже был с узлом на спине, а не семенил тоже.

**О слове ТОЖЕ**

Это слово может быть **частицей, союзом и наречием**, причем разные источники могут по-разному определять его функцию. Например, у Кустовой в теме ССП есть  союзы ТОЖЕ и ТАКЖЕ **с соединительно-отождествительным значением** (будучи **частицами** по происхождению, они стоят внутри предложения): Все обсуждали новый роман, я **тоже** решил его прочитать.

Разбору слова ТОЖЕ посвящена, например,  статья в Интернете http://www.labslsl.ru/?p=4&page=9

**Примечание.** Не стоит разбирать придуманные предложения вида "Я, с топором в руках, рубил дерево". Оно не имеет реального смысла.

Comment: @ Jasmin, по поводу придуманных предложений - согласен. Но данное предложение вполне нормальное.

Comment: А как еще можно рубить дерево, где еще может быть топор, если не в руках? Можно сказать: Я, с топором в руках, стоял рядом (это  определение).

Comment: Да, вы правы: не подумал об этом. Как вы думаете - это плеоназм?

Comment: Я думаю, что это семантическая ошибка.

Comment: Жасмин, дорогая, как я поняла, во всех приведенных предложениях обособляется определение. А первое предложение, конечно, неоднозначное, но я склонялась в пользу определения. Я какой? тоже с узлом. И с рюкзачком шла я (какая?), а не шла как?. Спасибо за вашу помощь!

Comment: @Jasmin, и все же, правильнее будет сказать, что это обособленное обстоятельство уточняющего типа. Здесь характеризующей признак выражен сильнее, чем обстоятельственный.

Comment: Поскольку несогласованные определения при обособлении приобретают часто оттенок обстоятельственного значения.

Answer (score 1):

Все верно. Я, тоже с узлом на спине(как? каким образом?), семенил за нею." Я, с рюкзачком за спиной(как? каким образом?), шла домой. Но: "Бабы(какие?), с длинными граблями в руках, бредут в поле.